# checkbox status lost after update panel works

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, updatepanel

I have an update panel, which fires every third seconds. I have this code into my asp.net page

```
<div ID="campaignDiv" runat="server" >
                            <ul>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

and I add its content dynamically like this:

```
 private string CreateLiCheckbox(string checkBoxText)
        {
            return string.Format("<li><span class=\"textDropdown\">{0}</span><input id=\"{1}\" value=\"{0}\" type=\"checkbox\"><label for=\"{1}\"></label></li>", checkBoxText, checkBoxText + "dropdownID");
        }
if (!IsPostBack) {
                List<string> comps = getCompainNames();
                string html = "<ul>";
                for (int i = 0; i < comps.Count(); i++) {
                    html = html + CreateLiCheckbox(comps[i]);
                }
                html = html + "</ul>";
                campaignDiv.InnerHtml = html;
            }
```

#### My problem

when the page loads, the checkboxes are like this:
[image: econd]

Then, I change the values to these:

[image]

but when the update pannel works, the page returns to its default statues, **where nothing of the checkboxes are selected**

could you help please?

Comment: Is this the same question you asked and I answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848875/asp-net-how-to-save-checkbox-satus-when-the-update-panel-works ?

Comment: Try to create a static boolean that is enable once you select the checkbox, then on load, set it according to the boolean.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I added the full code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23854794/checkbox-status-not-saved-when-update-panel-fires it is very simple code, please check it