# checkbox status not saved when update panel fires

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I have an div `id = campaignDiv` and I load its content dynamically

The content is checkboxes .

I have an update panel that fires every 30 seconds.

#### My problem

when the update panel fires, the checkboxes return to the default state, which is unselected.

I will give you all my code. Actually it is very simple code. **you can copy paste it in you visual studio and it will work**

**WebForm4.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm4.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestDropdownChecklist.WebForm4" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet1.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
                </asp:Timer>

                <div id="campaignDiv" runat="server">
                    <ul>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**WebForm4.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace TestDropdownChecklist
{
    public partial class WebForm4 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private string CreateLiCheckbox(string checkBoxText)
        {
            return string.Format("<li><span class=\"textDropdown\">{0}</span><input runat=\"server\" id=\"{1}\" value=\"{0}\" type=\"checkbox\"><label for=\"{1}\"></label></li>", checkBoxText, checkBoxText + "dropdownID");
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int refreshtime = 30000;
            Timer1.Interval = refreshtime;
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                string[] comps = new string[] { "default", "sales", "direct"};
                string html = "<ul>";
                for (int i = 0; i < comps.Count(); i++)
                {
                    html = html + CreateLiCheckbox(comps[i]);
                }
                html = html + "</ul>";
                campaignDiv.InnerHtml = html;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

    }
}
```

**StyleSheet1.css**

```
#DropdownSeviceLink {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

a#DropdownServiceLink:visited {
    color: inherit;
}

#campaignDiv {
    background-color: #374954;
    width: 200px;
    height: 170px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 0;
}

    #campaignDiv ul {
        color: #fff;
        list-style: none;
        overflow: auto;
        padding-left: 5px;
        height:100%;
    }

    #campaignDiv input[type=checkbox] {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

        #campaignDiv input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
            left: 60px;
            background: #26ca28;
        }

    #campaignDiv li {
        width: 100px; /*120*/
        height: 25px; /*40*/
        background: #333;
        margin: 13px 0px; /*20px 60px*/
        border-radius: 50px;
        position: relative;
    }

        #campaignDiv li:before {
            content: 'On';
            position: absolute;
            top: 4px; /*12*/
            left: 13px;
            height: 2px;
            color: #26ca28;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        #campaignDiv li:after {
            content: 'Off';
            position: absolute;
            top: 4px; /*12*/
            left: 71px; /*84*/
            height: 2px;
            color: #111;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        #campaignDiv li label {
            display: block;
            width: 36px; /*52*/
            height: 18px; /*22*/
            border-radius: 50px;
            -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
            -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
            -o-transition: all .5s ease;
            -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
            transition: all .5s ease;
            cursor: pointer;
            position: absolute;
            top: 4px; /*9*/
            z-index: 1;
            left: 12px;
            background: #ddd;
        }





.textDropdown {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    margin-left: 110px;

}
```

Please notice that I am using `runat server` already. maybe I should have added the checkbox dynamically in another way?

#### Edit

after readying through internet, I find that I may need to add the checkboxes to my update panel like this 
`UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(dynamic controls);`
but the problem is the the checkbox in my case is string not objects. right?

Your help is highly appreciated.

#### Edit for the great user Schadensbegrenzer

Your answer is really works, I thaaaaaaaaaaaaaank you , but please I stil have this issue not solved,
your code made this rendered html

```
<ul id="campaignDiv">   <li><input id="campaignDiv_0" type="checkbox" name="campaignDiv$0" checked="checked" value="default"><label for="campaignDiv_0">default</label></li>    <li><input id="campaignDiv_1" type="checkbox" name="campaignDiv$1" value="sales"><label for="campaignDiv_1">sales</label></li>  <li><input id="campaignDiv_2" type="checkbox" name="campaignDiv$2" value="direct"><label for="campaignDiv_2">direct</label></li>  </ul>
```

where the `campaignDiv` is the ID of the ul. kindly can you edit your answer so the rendered html can be like this:

```
<div id = campaignDiv>
    <ul>
              <li>
                        checkbox here
              </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

in your code I made the campaginDiv the id of `asp:CheckBoxList`

Comment: You are adding simple html controls which do not maintain state like asp.net controls do with the help of viewstate. However, is there a specific reason why you dont use a checkboxlist control? It seems that it would be exactly what you are looking for, wouldn`t it?

Comment: You are obviously rendering the same check boxes every time on page load event, so it is normal to see the same series of controls every time! use ViewState to simulate the asp.net controls behaviours.

Comment: @Schadensbegrenzer First I do added the `runat server` to my checkboxes so the asp.net should know the state, right? second you right maybe checkbxolist could be helpful but how to add it to `li` dynamically?

Comment: @AliShahrokhi no I don't think so because I am using `!ispostback`

Comment: @AliShahrokhi I edited the question for a note pleaes check

Comment: @Schadensbegrenzer I added a note in the question, please check

Comment: `<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" RepeatLayout="UnorderedList" />` will create checkbox within an unordered list.

Comment: @Schadensbegrenzer the code you gave is not c# code, it is asps code. Also, how could that solve my problem pleae? what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have more space for code here is my suggestion for the checkboxlist again. I hope it's that what you are asking for.

**.aspx**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upStuff" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="campaignDiv">
            <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" RepeatLayout="UnorderedList" ID="myCheckboxList" TextAlign="Left">
        </div>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick"/>
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**.aspx.cs**

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    var comps = new[] { "default", "sales", "direct" };
    for (int i = 0; i < comps.Count(); i++)
    {
         myCheckboxList.Items.Add(new ListItem{Text = comps[i]});
    }
}
```

This way it will keep your checkbox checked

Comment: I guess this could work, let me check please. I will take about 15 minutes to test, kindly wait . +1 anyway for your time with me my friend

Comment: just wrap the checkboxlist in a div. Is that what you mean? I edited my example accordingly

Comment: my friend, i really apprecatei your help. I will accept you answer now, but I still have problems though your code works perfectly. the problem is that in my previous html, the rendered html is different from the rendered html provided by your code. So, in order to give you more points, I will ask another question and tell you so you can answer there and take more points.

Comment: I guess it is because you had your text left side of the textbox. I updated the aspx code again. The CheckboxList does have a TextAlign property set to left now.

Answer (score 4):

First off, adding `runat="server"` to your html string is meaningless here, as it will not be processed by the server and will be sent to the client as is.

Now, your update panel will always emit the same content because its repopulated from the `ViewState`, if you disable the update panel view state, on the next refresh it will return an empty panel (there is no view state to read from)

So what to do here! You need to refresh the update panel contents on post back, and manually read the client state.

If view state size does concern you, then do the following:

```
public partial class WebForm4 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  private string CreateLiCheckbox(string checkBoxText)
  {
    var checkState = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form[string.Format("chk_{0}", checkBoxText)]) ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "";

    return string.Format("<li><span class=\"textDropdown\">{0}</span><input id=\"{1}\" name=\"chk_{0}\" value=\"{0}\" type=\"checkbox\" {2}><label for=\"{1}\"></label></li>",
      checkBoxText,
      checkBoxText + "dropdownID",
      checkState);
  }
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    int refreshtime = 5000;
    Timer1.Interval = refreshtime;

    if (!IsPostBack)
      PopulateCheckboxes();
  }
  protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    PopulateCheckboxes();
  }
  private void PopulateCheckboxes()
  {
    string[] comps = new string[] { "default", "sales", "direct" };
    string html = "<ul>";
    for (int i = 0; i < comps.Count(); i++)
    {
      html = html + CreateLiCheckbox(comps[i]);
    }
    html = html + "</ul>";
    campaignDiv.InnerHtml = html;
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, the checkbox still not save state after post back

Comment: OMG, it seems it is working. I will test again and update you

Comment: I don't know what to say, your code is completely working, but the other guy above really helps me. he is with me for 1.5 hour, and he gave a working code. I wish I wish I wish I could accept more than one answer. could u forgive me for not accepting your answer please?. also just to know what did you do?  all your changes are in this function righ? `CreateLiCheckbox` ? so I just need to copy paste it? again you are the one man, I like you

Comment: I also removed the `IsPostBack` check, since each time you have to refresh the update panel, using the solution I provided, you can safely disable the update panel view state, as it does not depend on it. Also view page source and compare the view state size with the other solution plus the extra __EVENTVALIDATION field in it. I was trying to explain a concept here .. its up to you to accept the answer that works best for you :)